# How to change the value of the select tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-select

I have two pages . "page1.php"  "page2.php"

**In page1.php ,**

```
<a href="page2.php?c=Category1">Category1</a>
<a href="page2.php?c=Category2">Category2</a>
<a href="page2.php?c=Category3">Category3</a>
```

**In page2.php,**

```
<?php
    $c=$_GET['c'];
    echo '<script>'
    , 'chgvalues("'.$c.'");'
    , '</script>';
?>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Category1</option>
    <option>Category3</option>
    <option>Category2</option>
</select>
```

**In chgvalues(c),**

```
function chgvalues(c)
{
    document.getElementById("mySelect").selected =true;
}
```

But this ain't working for me. What I want to do is , when a user clicks on a link on page 1 then the page 2 has the select value automatically set .

I think I am wrong in this **chgvalues**  function.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
function chgvalues(c)
{
    document.getElementById("mySelect").value = c;
}
```

and call `chgvalues` after `mySelect` is part of the dom.

To accomplish this you can simply call `chgvalues` after `mySelect` in the markup, e.g.

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option>Category1</option>
<option>Category3</option>
<option>Category2</option>
</select>
<?php
$c=$_GET['c'];// sanitize etc
echo '<script>'
, 'chgvalues("'.$c.'");'
, '</script>';
?>
```

or call it in window.onload, e.g.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        chgvalues("<?php echo $c; ?>");
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change page2.php to:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option id="Category1">Category1</option>
<option id="Category3">Category3</option>
<option id="Category2">Category2</option>
</select>
<?php
$c=$_GET['c'];
echo '<script>'
, 'chgvalues("'.$c.'");'
, '</script>';
?>
```

Your script is running before the options are in the DOM, and there are no IDs on the options so they don't match `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the query string value to the val method .

```
$("#mySelect").val("thevalue")
```

just make sure the value in the options tags matches the value in the val method.

Comment: What `.val()` method? Please let the OP know which external library you are suggesting...

Answer (score 0):

Try

In page2.php

```
<?php
$c=$_GET['c'];
echo '<script>'
. 'chgvalues("'.$c.'");'
. '</script>';
?>
<select id="mySelect">
<option value='Category1'>Category1</option>
<option value='Category3'>Category3</option>
<option value='Category2'>Category2</option>
</select>
```

And in `chgvalues(c)`

```
function chgvalues(c)
 {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").value = true;
 }
```

Comment: I guess that true should be c , isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "selected" attribute applies to the `<option>` tag, and not the `<select>` tag. In fact, just change page2.php to:

```
<?php $c = $_GET[c];?>
<select>
<option <?php if(c == "1"){echo "selected";}?>>Category1</option>
<option <?php if(c == "3"){echo "selected";}?>>Category3</option>
<option <?php if(c == "2"){echo "selected";}?>>Category2</option>
</select>
```